# OSMAND commercial support

Tags: openstreetmap, osmdroid, osmand

A couple of days ago I sent an email to the contact address in the official OSMAND site, but have not received an answer yet. I'm now asking here in case someone affiliated with the project reads this. The company I work for needs a custom development on top of OSMAND, and it's willing to financially support the project in exchange for this.

Does anyone here know how to reach the right person for this?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest to wait 1-2 days longer. If you still don't get a reply then try https://github.com/osmandapp/Osmand. The developers are pretty active there.